# "Motivic structure on higher homotopy of non-nilpotent spaces" ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, reference-request

Has anyone an idea where one can read more about Deepam Patel's talk "Motivic structure on higher homotopy of non-nilpotent spaces" http://www.ihes.fr/~abbes/SGA/patel.html ?

Edit/Answer: The video is here: http://www.ihes.fr/~abbes/SGA/suron-kika-passe.html

Comment: Did you ask Deepam Patel?

Comment: The email adress given in his papers (at least in those I looked up) did not work.

Comment: In case this helps: http://mypage.iu.edu/~patelde/

Comment: I took the email adress from the papers on that site too, it did not work.

Comment: Deepam is currently a postdoc at VU Amsterdam.  I believe that his email address is deeppatel1981@gmail.com.

Comment: Thomas, you should put the video link as an answer and accept it. As it is CW, you won't get points, if you are worried about that.

Comment: @David: Yes, the talk is very good, so one could see it as answer, but I wait until the preprints are free available. @Andy: Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprint is available on his site at the IHES.

http://www.ihes.fr/~patel/motivichom.pdf